# MVC4 can't connect to SQL Server 2008 remote DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have looked at past questions on this but I can't solve my problem

I am having problems connecting a simple database to MVC project. This is very difficult to do and I am using VS2010, SQL Server 2008 (remote DB). I have a DB already created and I want to use code first with Entity Framework. Sounds easy as I just follow a tutorial but no tutorial I used has ever worked. The tutorials use older MVC and older Entity Framework. I have MVC4 and EF 5

Here are the steps I am using

1. create new MVC project and in references I see Entity Framework
2. create class which will correspond to a table not yet created in the DB
3. add connection string to `web.config`
4. add extra line to `global.asax` to avoid an error entity 5 throws up (found out about this from other peoples problems with this)
5. add controller with db and dbcontext
6. run project and as you could guess a problem occurs with controller called video

Error:

> *Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object
>   name 'dbo.videos'.*

I have no idea and this MVC seems a lot more unstable than web forms as I can connect to the same DB in webforms without an issue .

```
 <add  name="videoDBContext"
       connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;    Password=xxx"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Class:

```
public class video
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
public class videoDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<video> videos{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.videos.ToList()); //
  Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.videos'.
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an ASP.NET MVC issue, it's an Entity Framework issue.  Assuming these are new tables, at some point the SQL tables have to actually be generated.  I've never used EF with code first, but I would guess your problem, which I read as "add tables and relationships to existing database from code first models" may have something to do with Code First Migrations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting to the Database fine. The actual DB model and the codefirst model are not in sync, hence the error.

You're adding a DbSet to the DBContext for video, but no such table exists within your current database. Unless your database initializer states to create the models when it does not exist, this is exactly the error I'd expect you to get.

Also, I see no mapping class defined or mentioned that maps the model class back to the database table.

Take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application. This gets into database intializers towards the end. The other option is to simply create the table manually.

So, problem one, no database initializer (or pre-defined table). Problem two, no mapping class for the table and OnModelCreating, at least from what you've shown. It's entirely possible that you're not using the fluent api to define your mappings and instead are just using attributes in the video model, but again, you didn't show that, so I'm going to show you the fluent way.

EDIT:

I've updated this code from a test project I created locally with your naming conventions. This 100% works. These are the exact class I created or reverse engineered.

```
public class videoDBContext : DbContext
{
    static videoDBContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<videoDBContext>(null);
    }

    public videoDBContext()
        : base("Name=videoDBContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Video> Videos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new VideoMap());
    }
}
```

domain class

```
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and the mapping class

```
public class VideoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Video>
{
    public VideoMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Video");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");
    }
}
```

and then my controller action

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        using (videoDBContext context = new videoDBContext())
        {
            var list = context.Videos.ToList();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

This returns whatever "videos" I added to the table.

As for what goes where, it doesn't really matter if you're doing everything in one project. Pick a spot. Here's how things shook out in mine.

[image]

You have to remember there's additional upfront effort when working with code first to get things up and running. Once you get the hang of it however, it's a really nice way of working with databases.

Comment: I already pre-created a video table before  hand so what do i do now?

Comment: I dont see any mapping class in any tutorial before? where does this go in class file? This seems very complicated for s simple connection.

Comment: I've updated my response with the exact classes of a working example I built locally using your names.

Comment: the class you added mapping class, I need to include this code ?I have a table already made so do I need this?                     using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

Comment: I get this error The 'ID' property on 'video' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.

Comment: 1) The mapping class allows you more fine tuned control over your DB schema. Code first will by convention infer the table based off the domain object. So while you don't necessarily need it, at some point you'll more than likely want it. 2) Your second message is just that. You have a datatype mismatch somewhere on the ID field. It's expecting an int and you tried to save a string to it. Good luck.

Comment: No I need help with this because I dont have an Int for ID and I cant run the project without getting the error. The data type in nchar(10).  All I have is this for ID // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.ID);