# Retreiving data from sql server 2008 to ASP.NET MVC 4 either by using Stored procedure or Entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.ENT MVC and I am working on project where I have data in SQL Server 2008. Now I need to connect to that database using ASP.NET MVC4 and retrieve data. Now I am confused between two approaches- either I have to use Stored procedure or entity framework. In this project I will be dealing with database which already been developed.Here stored procedure has been used. So obviously my colleagues options will be stored procedure. 
But what I know about entity framework is it is user friendly and helps in developing application faster compared to stored procedure.

Please friends don't be confused. I am not asking here which one is best. Since both SP and EF are new to me and EF seems cleaner and easier compared to SP, i decided to use Entity framework. I know SP performance is better compared to EF, but I am not worried much about that. So apart from that if you have any other reason please let me know so i can rethink about my decision.
Thnaks

Comment: Why not use Entity Framework?

Comment: My tip would be to go for EntityFramework or Linq2Sql

Comment: @DawoodAwan u mean i need to look for tutorial about entity framework? I am new to this. if you know any good source could you please mention here..

Comment: @NoLifeKing Hi thanks for reply.If you have any source could you please mention here so i can have a look into that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx This is the chapter at MSDN

Comment: And here's a tutorial with Code First by Scott Gu http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Comment: @NoLifeKing thank you very much. I think i have to spend some time in understanding this concept.:)..it is really a good tutorial..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use Sql Server or SqlExpress instead of LocalDb maybe the following can help you.

http://amitraya.blogspot.gr/2012/05/create-websites-using-sql-express-with.html
http://tutorials.slcdev.com/2012/03/mvc4-sqlexpress-connection/

Answer (score 1):

I have found great article on this site http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft site...
[MVC4 can't connect to SQL Server 2008 remote DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655700/mvc4-cant-connect-to-sql-server-2008-remote-db)
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/creating-a-connection-string